# How to use BasePostprocessor to resize bitmap selectively

Tags: android, fresco

I need to cut some of the images if they are taller than the maximum texture size of the device, and do not do anything if they are not. Based on the documentation, since I will do resizing, so I need to use the following method:

```
CloseableReference<Bitmap> process(Bitmap sourceBitmap, PlatformBitmapFactory bitmapFactory);
```

That means I have to create a new bitmap anyway even if I don't have to. (in case the image's size are not bigger than the max texture size). That implies more memory usage and more CUP time spent. My question is that is there a way to just apply this postprocessing only if it's needed.

Here is my process function

```
@Override
public CloseableReference<Bitmap> process(Bitmap sourceBitmap, PlatformBitmapFactory bitmapFactory) {

    final int height = sourceBitmap.getHeight();
    final int maxTextureSize = ImageUtils.getMaxTextureSize();

    if (height > maxTextureSize) {
        return bitmapFactory.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), maxTextureSize,
                sourceBitmap.getConfig());
    } else {
        return bitmapFactory.createBitmap(sourceBitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got some help from Facebook friends, using a regional decoder to partially decode a huge bitmap will solve this problem and become more memory friendly.

The example they provided is here:

https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/baa629dd46797a3342a50b918ea0989b63819c87/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/imagepipeline/ImagePipelineRegionDecodingFragment.java